# Bining a set of numbers in a specific way

Tags: python, pandas, numbers

I want to split a set of numbers from 100 (inclusive) to 200 (inclusive) in bins. The numbers are needed to be split in those intervals: [100, 135), [135, 160), [160, 175), [175, 190), [190, 200]. Unfortunately, for now, I have not found a function that solves my problem perfectly

I have tried pd.cut function with a `right` parameter that was set to `False`, but the output of all possible intervals was: [100, 135), [135, 160), [160, 175), [175, 190), [190, 200]. The difference is that I need to have last interval to include 200 (so [190, 200], not [190, 200)).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre], so that we can see the data structure you start with and the data structure you want at the end? *(I could guess and write an answer where you have a dataframe with one series containing the values and want a new series containing the bin. But if I guessed wrong I would have wasted my time, and I don't intend to waste my time.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(1000, 2004)).div(10)
```

s:

```
0       100.0
1       100.1
2       100.2
3       100.3
4       100.4
        ...  
999     199.9
1000    200.0 <-- exactly 200
1001    200.1
1002    200.2
1003    200.3
Length: 1004, dtype: float64
```

---

**Code**

How about additionally processing the case where **value is exactly 200** with boolean masking in the result of the `pd.cut` function?

```
bins=[100, 135, 160, 175, 190, 200]
labels=['[100, 135)', '[135, 160)', '[160, 175)', '[175, 190)', '[190, 200]']
cond = s.eq(200)
out = pd.cut(s, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False).mask(cond, '[190, 200]')
```

out:

```
0       [100, 135)
1       [100, 135)
2       [100, 135)
3       [100, 135)
4       [100, 135)
           ...    
999     [190, 200]
1000    [190, 200] <-- exactly 200
1001           NaN
1002           NaN
1003           NaN
Length: 1004, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): ['[100, 135)' < '[135, 160)' < '[160, 175)' < '[175, 190)' < '[190, 200]']
```

Comment: A perfect and the best solution right there, exactly what I need to have! Many thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you just need to make the last bin right boundary more than the actual inclusive boundry you want, e.g., `201` or `200.1` since you are specifying `right=False`:

```
import pandas as pd

nums = pd.Series(range(100, 201))  
bins_with_labels = pd.cut(
    x=nums,
    bins=[100, 135, 160, 175, 190, 201],  # For the last bin, you need to use a number larger than the final inclusive right boundary. 
    labels=['[100, 135)', '[135, 160)', '[160, 175)', '[175, 190)', '[190, 200]'],
    right=False,
    include_lowest=True,
)
grouped = nums.groupby(bins_with_labels).apply(list)
print(grouped)
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 135)  [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134]
[135, 160)  [135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159]
[160, 175)  [160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174]
[175, 190)  [175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189]
[190, 200]  [190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but the solution you are providing is not 100% working for me, since the numbers between 200 and that number that is a bit bigger than 200 (whether there are float numbers) will be included in [190, 200], which is not fully correct. But anyway, many thanks!

Comment: The won't? `nums = pd.Series(range(100, 201))`  doesn't have any of those (the largest number is 200)? That's what is "cut", look at the output for it above?